# curl splunk strftime give Unparsable URI-encoded request data

Tags: curl, splunk

When I use eval time=strftime(_time, "%Y-%m-%d") in curl, I get Unparsable URI-encoded request data, could you please help?

Comment: Try url-encoding the input so that it's valid, for example `%` would be encoded as `%25`

Comment: used --data0yrkebcide  and it's working now. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

used --data-urlencode and solved the problem